# Deploying Parse server with Parse Live Query on AWS elasticbeanstalk

Tags: elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, parse-server

I have deployed **NodeJs** Parse server with [Parse LiveQuery](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-LiveQuery) on AWS elasticbeanstalk but it seems like LiveQuery is not working. When i try to subscribe from my iOS client app it gives me error.

> Error: Error Domain=SRWebSocketErrorDomain Code=2132 "received bad
> response code from server 404"

**Note:** When I run locally on my mac it works fine. What could be the issue with AWS ?

Comment: Looks similar: http://serverfault.com/questions/774446/how-to-run-a-parse-live-query-server-web-sockets-behind-an-aws-load-balancer?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar issue as here:

[How to run a Parse Live Query Server (Web Sockets) behind an AWS Load Balancer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/774446/how-to-run-a-parse-live-query-server-web-sockets-behind-an-aws-load-balancer?rq=1)

The problem seemed to be that classic load balancers don't support websockets.

AWS recently launched a new service, Application Load Balancers, which support websockets:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/

Comment: Application load balancers Perfect thanks for this